# Getting a hover menu to work in IE9

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I need a hover menu to work in IE9. It works in IE 10 and IE Edge. I'm not sure how to go about fixing it. I think it might be this .subnav_wrapper_ul:first in the JS and I'm not sure how to go about and fix it.

MY HTML

```
<div id="main-menu" class="collapse navbar-collapse mainMenu">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav home-nav">
        <li class="nav_active"><a href="javascript:void(0);">HOME</a></li>
        <li class="nav_item">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">ABOUT US </a>
                <ul class="subnav_wrapper_ul">
                    <li class="subnav_item">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
                        <a class="" href="http://www.profishinsea.co.uk/client_area/nicole/noor-tech/our-vision.html">Our Vision</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="subnav_item">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
                        <a class="" href="http://www.profishinsea.co.uk/client_area/nicole/noor-tech/our-vision.html">Our Team</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav_active"><a href="javascript:void(0);">CONTACT US</a></li>    
    </ul>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
.collapse.navbar-collapse {
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.mainMenu {
    width: 80% !important;
}

.nav {
    font-family: "Titillium Web",sans-serif;
    padding-left: 5% !important;
}
.nav a {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 16px !important;
}

.home-nav {
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
}

.nav_active a{
    color: #ff9e19 !important;
}

.subnav_wrapper_ul {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 121px;
}
.subnav_wrapper_ul li {
    list-style: outside none none;
    padding: 0 0 0 7px;
}
.subnav_wrapper_ul a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0 !important;
    padding: 4px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

My JS

```
$('ul.navbar-nav li').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).find('.subnav_wrapper_ul:first').css('display','block');
    },
        function () {
            $(this).find('.subnav_wrapper_ul:first').css('display','none');  
    }
);
```

Comment: try simple CSS instead of javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with css:

```
ul.navbar-nav li:hover > ul{ display:block; }
```

Comment: @Chibi css trics are always better. Glad this helped.

Answer (score 0):

1. IE doesn’t support the `:hover` pseudo element on non-a tags, but
   I’d already solved that issue.  I tried many solutions others
   listed: **Adding a a proper doctype to avoid quirks mode**.
2. Get **`<a>` to behave like a `<div>` by displaying it as a block item**,
   then style it as you would style your `div`.

   hover on a div in standard browsers

   The code that corrects the IE bug:

   ```
   a {display:block; width:148px; height:140px; background:red}
   a:hover {background:green;}

   <a href=”#”>&nbsp;</a>
   ```

   Note:

   Even when your intention is not to create a link, you can use the
    tag to mimic a block element by giving it a block style,
   allowing you to use the :hover pseudo-class without worrying about
   IE6. If you don’t want the cursor to change into a hand when people
   mouseover the image (this happens automatically when using the 
   tag), just apply the following style:

   ```
   a:hover {cursor:default}
   ```

   [source](http://stylisticweb.com/design-tutorials/15-ie6-bugs-and-simple-solutions)